# GCP| Composer Dataproc submit job| Auth credential not found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

I am running a GCP composer cluster on GKE. I am defining a DAG to submit a job to dataproc cluster. I have read GCP doc, and it says that Composer's service account will get used by the workers to send the dataproc api requests.

But DataprocSubmitJobOperator reports error in getting the auth credentials.
Stack trace below. Composer env info attached.
I need suggestion to fix this issue.

```
[2022-08-23, 16:03:25 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1448} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=harshit.bapna@dexterity.ai
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=dataproc_spark_operators
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=pyspark_task
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-08-23T16:03:16.986859+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2022-08-23T16:03:16.986859+00:00
[2022-08-23, 16:03:25 UTC] {dataproc.py:1847} INFO - Submitting job
[2022-08-23, 16:03:25 UTC] {credentials_provider.py:312} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.
[2022-08-23, 16:03:25 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1776} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py", line 1849, in execute
    job_object = self.hook.submit_job(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 439, in inner_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/dataproc.py", line 869, in submit_job
    client = self.get_job_client(region=region)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/dataproc.py", line 258, in get_job_client
    credentials=self._get_credentials(), client_info=CLIENT_INFO, client_options=client_options
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 261, in _get_credentials
    credentials, _ = self._get_credentials_and_project_id()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 240, in _get_credentials_and_project_id
    credentials, project_id = get_credentials_and_project_id(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/utils/credentials_provider.py", line 321, in get_credentials_and_project_id
    return _CredentialProvider(*args, **kwargs).get_credentials_and_project()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/utils/credentials_provider.py", line 229, in get_credentials_and_project
    credentials, project_id = self._get_credentials_using_adc()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/utils/credentials_provider.py", line 307, in _get_credentials_using_adc
    credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=self.scopes)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 459, in default
    credentials, project_id = checker()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 221, in _get_explicit_environ_credentials
    credentials, project_id = load_credentials_from_file(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 107, in load_credentials_from_file
    raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File celery was not found.
[2022-08-23, 16:03:25 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1279} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=dataproc_spark_operators, task_id=pyspark_task, execution_date=20220823T160316, start_date=20220823T160324, end_date=20220823T160325
[2022-08-23, 16:03:25 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:93} ERROR - Failed to execute job 32837 for task pyspark_task (File celery was not found.; 356144)
[2022-08-23, 16:03:26 UTC] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-08-23, 16:03:26 UTC] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

[GCP Composer Env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBWjk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error `File celery was not found`, I think that the Application Default Credentials (ADC) tries to read a file named `celery`, and it doesn't find it, so check if you set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, because if you set it, ADC will read the the file to use it:

> - If the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set, ADC uses the service account key or configuration file that the variable points to.
> - If the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS isn't set, ADC uses the service account that is attached to the resource that is running your code.
>   This service account might be a default service account provided by Compute Engine, Google Kubernetes Engine, App Engine, Cloud Run, or Cloud Functions. It might also be a user-managed service account that you created.

GCP [doc](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting it. I have read this doc before. The attached image in my orig post, points that there is a service account configured for this composer environment. Hence environment's SA account should get picked by the worker but something is getting messed up. I can login to the composer worker and do
`XXX@cloudshell:/google/credentials (dev-shr-main-d6130be-dcfe237c)$ env | grep GOOGLE
GOOGLE_CLOUD_SHELL=true
GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=dev-shr-main-d6130be-dcfe237c
BASHRC_GOOGLE_PATH=/google/devshell/bashrc.google`

Should there be GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var?

Comment: just try `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`,  if it is not an empty line, you should unset the env var from your composer configurations